# How to keep graphics when resizing C# form

Tags: c#

I am working on a program where I need to draw rectangle graphics onto the form itself, when I click the form. I created code to do this *(below)*, but when I resize the form the rectangles are deleted.

How do I retain the drawn rectangles when the form is resized?

```cs
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    Pen Haitham = new Pen(Color.Silver, 2);
    g.FillRectangle(Haitham.Brush, new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 50, 50));
}
```

Comment: As others pointed out, use the Paint event to draw your graphics.  Here is some additional information:  http://www.bobpowell.net/picturebox.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this instead:

```
    private List<Point> _points = new List<Point>();

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        foreach(Point point in _points)
        {
            using (Pen Haitham = new Pen(Color.Silver, 2))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Haitham.Brush, new Rectangle(point.X, point.Y, 50, 50));
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _points.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        Invalidate(); // could be optimized to invalidate only the future rectangle draw
    }
```

In Windows with Winforms (or native Windows), you supposed to override OnPaint and do almost all your paint logic there.

Note with WPF, it would be different, you would compose a scene adding elements to it (here you would add a Rectangle shape to a Canvas for example).

Comment: Could you please clarify this code why I should do that ? what is the idea ?

Comment: Overriding OnPaint is the standard way of doing custom rendering. See the official doc here for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You must do the `"Graphics"` things in the `"Paint"` event. Then you can see your rectangle always, because the event fires whenever windows needed to invalidate the paintings.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too terribly familiar with graphics, but I am assuming that you would need to put all of your drawing objects into a container and have them redrawn when the form is sized. You might need to recall all of your paining objects in the sizeChanged event.